# "for" loop inside a screen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I need to run the same command say 10k times and I don't need it to run in foreground.

```
screen -dmS "ScreenName" for i in {1..10000}; do <command> arg$i; done
```

doesn't work for me.

How do I start `for` loop inside a detached screen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` is a bash builtin, not a command. Run another bash in screen that runs the loop:

```
screen -dmS "ScreenName" bash -c 'for i in {1..10000}; do echo $i ; sleep .1 ; done'
```

Answer (score 0):

put it inside a file and start it with nohup. It will disassociate the process from your terminal window. It will run until your loop is over, it crashes, or process is terminated.

```
nohup ./filehere &
```